# How to migrate from iPhoto to Windows Live Photo Gallery?

Tags: export, import, iphoto, events, windows-live-photo

I'm moving back from Mac to Windows and I want to take all of my photos with me. I'm specifically concerned about keeping event names, I don't so much care about Faces or Places.

Is there anything I can use to export everything out of iPhoto, while keeping Event information, that will be understood when adding/importing to Windows Live Photo Gallery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how to get event data from iPhoto into Windows Live Photo gallery, but [phoshare](http://code.google.com/p/phoshare/) made things much easier - I just copied the generated photo structure to a folder in 'My Pictures'.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the answers from microsoft will help:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/switch-from-mac-to-pcwindows-7-how-do-i-move-my/f1cd1f7f-92ce-479e-b38a-c2c37d1a6772

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to use free software [Phototheca](http://lunarship.com) for Windows  (I participated in creation of this app) to organize your photos in the same way as in iPhoto.

In Phototheca you can import all your photos and it will create events automatically basing on time stamp of photo (exactly as iPhoto does) and later you are able to merge or split events as you wish to organize them.

In your case I guess you may import whole folder 'My Pictures' into this app and most of your events should pop up automatically (of course some adjustments may be required later).

My experience is that I imported near 10,000 my photos with lot of events and can say it handles them very well, no hangs or slowdown, just works.

Below is a screenshot:
[image: screenshot of Phototheca]